# Unable to determine type of account from banno consumer api

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

When my plugin retrieves data from the banno consumer api, Credit Cards, Mortgages, and Investment accounts are all coming through with an account type and subtype that look like this

```
type: "Third Party"
subtype: "Other"
```

My plugin needs to be able to determine the difference between these types of accounts, however the Banno consumer api does not define Credit Card or Mortgage as an account type. Furthermore, the documentation states that the subtype field should not be used.

Does the banno consumer api provide any way to accurately determine the type of Credit Card, Mortgage, Investment, or any of these "Third Party" accounts?

Answer (score 0):

The `accountType` of "Other" is a result of the way that an account is configured within the underlying core (and there are 4 cores that Jack Henry supports..3 for banks and 1 for credit unions).

There often isn't much information available within the core *itself* about the account, which is how you end up with an `accountType` of "Other" and `accountSubType` of "Third Party".

There *are* credit cards represented (with `accountType` of "Line of Credit" and `accountSubType` of "Credit Card"), depending upon the configuration.

Mortgages generally aren't represented directly via `accountType` and `accountSubType` and the best that is known from the core is that the account is some type of "Loan".

Comment: More info: "'Other' accounts are not considered in-house accounts for Banks and CUs. They are typically external accounts that have been setup in the core with very limited data which is updated on the core from the third party vendor usually on a daily (data is not real-time). It's likely these accounts will need to be ignored from the Banno consumer API if you are looking for in-house accounts. The source of data for these external accounts should be the 3rd Party Vendor."